# Aurelia and primeui components

Tags: aurelia, prime-ui

I come from the JSF world and just got a chance to play around with Aurelia which seem absolutely marvellous.

So I've started to see if I can make my prime componentes into Aurelia but I have'nt succeeded yet.

I spent some time trying to use the same strategy as [How to use JQuery UI components in Aurelia getting started app (navigation app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31176580/how-to-use-jquery-ui-components-in-aurelia-getting-started-app-navigation-app)

But it's not working.

For instance in strict javascript I'would use something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#myid').puibutton();
}
```

and html:

```
<button id="myid" type="button">MyButton</button>
```

But this will not work when injecting $ from 'jquery'.

If anyone have a recommendation on how to push forward I would be most grateful.

br

/hw

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.

My customAttribute needed

```
import 'jquery-ui';
import 'primeui';
import 'jquery-ui/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css!';
export class .....
```