# Aurelia cannot find jQuery UI components

Tags: jquery, datepicker, tabs, aurelia

**I've post the solution down below.** I'm open to suggestions on how to improve though, so, please don't hesitate to suggest a better way!

I'm using Aurelia CLI for my web-app. I'm trying to use jQuery tabs and jQuery datepicker, but nothing works

I've got a demo on gitHub [here](https://github.com/gitKearney/aurelia-jquery-datepicker) where all you have to do is clone, then run

```
npm install; au run
```

I'm using the example provided in this StackOverflow question [How to use JQuery UI components in Aurelia getting started app (navigation app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31176580/how-to-use-jquery-ui-components-in-aurelia-getting-started-app-navigation-app)

If you look in *src/routes/tabs* you'll see I'm including I'm including jQuery by using

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import {tabs} from 'jquery-ui';
```

In my `aurelia.json`, I'm including *jquery* and *jquery-ui* via the lines

```
"dependencies": [
  "jquery",
  "jquery-ui"
]
```

If I change the the import to

```
"jquery",
{
  "name": "jquery-ui",
  "path": "../node_modules/jquery-ui",
  "main": "jquery-ui"
  "deps": ["jquery"],
  "exports": "$"
}
```

I still get no error. The code just does nothing.

I suspect the root cause is a configuration issue, but any help would be super appreciated!

Comment: You're missing a comma after `"main": "jquery-ui"`. Maybe that's it?

Comment: oh, sorry, that's a copy paste error :-(

if you miss a comma, or add an extra comman, the `au` command will blow a bunch of errors

Comment: Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837505/how-to-use-jquery-ui-with-aurelia

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to solve the problem.

Modify `aurelia/aurelia.json` to include the jquery. Then, load the jquery-ui plugin you want, and give jquery as a dependency. Also, load in the CSS for it

```
"jquery",
{
  "name": "jquery-ui-datepicker",
  "path": "../node_modules/jquery-ui/",
  "main": "ui/widgets/datepicker",
  "dep": ["jquery"],
  "exports": "$",
  "resources": [
    "themes/base/datepicker.css",
    "themes/base/theme.css"
  ]
}
```

Then in my view, I had to add this code

```
<!-- the view.html -->
<input datepicker value.bind="dateSelected">
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
</script>
```

Then, I had to use a customAttribute to listen for jQuery's onchange() event

```
<!-- the view.html -->
<require from="./datepicker"></require>
```

The code to listen for jQuery's *onchange()* event

```
// datepicker.js
import {inject, customAttribute} from 'aurelia-framework';

@customAttribute('datepicker')
@inject(Element)
export class DatePicker {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  attached() {
    $(this.element).datepicker()
      .on('change', e => fireEvent(e.target, 'input'));

  }

  detached() {
    $(this.element).datepicker('destroy')
      .off('change');
  }
}

function createEvent(name) {
  var event = document.createEvent('Event');
  event.initEvent(name, true, true);
  return event;
}

function fireEvent(element, name) {
  var event = createEvent(name);
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Here's a [link](https://github.com/gitKearney/aurelia-jquery-datepicker) to the github solution. If there's a better way to do it, I'm open to suggestions.